# Javascript module include in protractor configuration js file

Tags: javascript, protractor, allure

I have created a customized-jasmin-allure-reporter.js class where I wrote the report configuration methods similar like jasime2Allure reporter module except some minor changes. Now I would like to include this file into protractor configuration.js file from where I want to generate custome allure report using this. But unfortunately I found error all the time Error: Error: Cannot find module 'customized-jasmin-allure-reporter'.

MyCustomized class is

```
 var Allure = require('allure-js-commons');
 var path = require('path');
 var allure = new Allure();


  function CustomizedJasminAllureReporter(userDefinedConfig, allureReporter) {
var Status = {PASSED: 'passed', FAILED: 'failed', BROKEN: 'broken', PENDING: 'pending'};
this.allure = allureReporter || allure;

..................

     }

     exports.allureReporter = allure;
    exports.CustomizedJasminAllureReporter =CustomizedJasminAllureReporter;
```

My Protractor configuration file is

```
    exports.config = {

troubleshoot: true, // for protractor
allScriptsTimeout: 1500000,
restartBrowserBetweenTests: false,

specs: [
    './e2e/tests/**/*.e2e-spec.ts',
],

capabilities:
    {
        'browserName' : 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': { 'args' : ['--disable-extensions']},
        'shardTestFiles': true,
        'maxInstances': 1,
        'unexpectedAlertBehaviour' : 'dismiss'
    },
    ..............
onPrepare: function() {

    var AllureReporter = require('customized-jasmin-allure-reporter');

    // get the browser name
    var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
    capsPromise.then(function(caps) {
        console.log(caps);
        var browserName = caps.get('browserName');
        var browserVersion = caps.get('version');
        browser.browserNameforSpec = browserName + "-" + browserVersion + "-";
        console.log(browser.browserNameforSpec);
    });

    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    require('ts-node').register({
        project: 'e2e/tsconfig.json'
    });

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
        resultsDir: 'allure-results'

    }));
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);

    jasmine.getEnv().afterEach(function (done) {
            browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
                allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', function () {
                    return new Buffer(png, 'base64')
                },'image/png')();
                done();
            })
    });
 }
  };
```

Comment: Your custom reporter is not imported properly.`var AllureReporter = require('customized-jasmin-allure-reporter');`

Answer (score 0):

Your custom reporter is not imported properly.

```
`var AllureReporter = require('./src/...');` //Provide relative or absolute path of your report file.
```